# Login failing when using correct credentials with MongoDB and Express Server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

When i am logging in with the correct credentials it is saying they are invalid
and i can not figure out why.

auth.routes.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const User = require('../models/user.model.js'); // 
    
    // User registration endpoint
    router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body;
        console.log(`Registration attempt for username: ${username}, email: ${email}`); // Log the attempted registration details
        try {
            let user = await User.findOne({ email });
            if (user) {
                console.log(`User already exists with email: ${email}`); // Log if user already exists
                return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User already exists' });
            }
    
            console.log(`Creating new user with email: ${email}`);
            user = new User({
                username,
                email,
                password
            });
    
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    
            await user.save();
            console.log(`User created successfully: ${user.id}`);
    
            const payload = {
                user: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            };
    
            jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 360000 }, (err, token) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(`Error generating JWT for user: ${email}`, err);
                    throw err; // Log and throw the error if JWT generation fails
                }
                console.log(`JWT generated for user: ${email}`);
                res.json({ token });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Server error during registration for username: ${username}, email: ${email}`, err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server error');
        }
    });
    
    
    // Simplified User login endpoint with detailed diagnostic logging
    router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        console.log(`[Login Attempt] Email: ${email}`);
    
        try {
            // Step 1: Find the user by email
            const user = await User.findOne({ email });
            if (!user) {
                console.log(`[Error] No user found for email: ${email}`);
                return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' });
            }
            console.log(`[Success] User found for email: ${email}, Username: ${user.username}`);
    
            // Step 2: Compare the submitted password with the user's stored hashed password
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`[Error] bcrypt comparison error: `, err);
                    return res.status(500).send('Server error during password comparison');
                }
                if (!isMatch) {
                    console.log(`[Mismatch] Password does not match for user: ${email}`);
                    console.log(`[Debug] Submitted password: ${password}`); // # FOR DEBUG ONLY
                    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' });
                }
    
                // Step 3: Password matches, proceed to generate JWT
                console.log(`[Success] Password matches for user: ${email}`);
                const payload = {
                    user: { id: user.id }
                };
    
                jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 360000 }, (err, token) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(`[Error] JWT generation error for user: ${email}`, err);
                        return res.status(500).send('Server error during JWT generation');
                    }
                    console.log(`[Success] JWT generated for user: ${email}`);
                    res.json({ token });
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`[Server Error] During login for user: ${email}`, err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server error');
        }
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

user.model.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    
    // Define the schema for our user model
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            trim: true, // Removes whitespace from both ends of a string
            minlength: 3 // Minimum length of the username
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            trim: true, // Removes whitespace from both ends of a string
            match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address'] // Regex to validate email format
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 6 // Minimum length of the password
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true // Automatically adds createdAt and updatedAt fields
    });
    
    // Pre-save hook to hash the password before saving it to the database
    userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
        // Only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
        if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
    
        try {
            // Generate a salt and use it to hash the password
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    });
    
    // Instance method to check if the provided password matches the hashed password in the database
    userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function(enteredPassword) {
        return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
    };
    
    // Create the model from the schema and export it
    const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users');
    
    module.exports = User;
```

output i am getting

`"Server started on port 5000 MongoDB Connected [Login Attempt] Email: email i used [Success] User found for email: email i used, Username: username i used [Mismatch] Password does not match for user: email i used [Debug] Submitted password: password"`

I have signed up succesfully with the output

`_id 65c51a381f0331aa2edfb9d5 username "username i used" email "email i used" password "$2a$ hashed pass" createdAt 2024-02-08T18:15:20.965+00:00 updatedAt 2024-02-08T18:15:20.965+00:00 __v 0`

in the database, but when i login it says invalid credentials.

If you have any idea what i could do here to fix this, please let me know. I have been debugging none stop and i originally thought the password wasnt being compared properly when logging in, but it is as i printed in the debug logs and it outputted as the decrypted password, thanks.